# HTML page which takes the input, runs the R code and gives the result back to HTML

Tags: html, r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to design a front end to display the result of my R code which takes 2 files,master.csv and detail.csv. 
Master.csv contains reference data with 2 columns which contains Commodity Category and Commodity Name as shown below:

```
Sl.No. Commodity Category Commodity Name
1      Stationary         Pencil
2      Stationary         Pen
3      Stationary         Marker
4      Office Utensils    Chair
5      Office Utensils    Drawer
6      Hardware           Monitor
7      Hardware           CPU
```

Detail.csv contains the user data which contains various Commodity names as shown below:

```
Sl.No. Commodity Name
1      Pancil
2      Pencil-HB 02
3      Pencil-Apsara
4      Pancil-Nataraj
5      Pen-Parker
6      Pen-Reynolds
7      Monitor-X001RL
```

The output I get is corrected commodity names classified into their respective Commodity Categories like shown below :

```
Commodity.Name.Old Commodity.Name Commodity.Category
1             Pancil         Pencil         Stationary
2       Pencil-HB 02         Pencil         Stationary
3      Pencil-Apsara         Pencil         Stationary
4     Pancil-Nataraj         Pencil         Stationary
5         Pen-Parker            Pen         Stationary
6       Pen-Reynolds            Pen         Stationary
7     Monitor-X001RL        Monitor           Hardware
```

The following is the R code which does this correction and classification:

```
library(stringdist)
library(dplyr)

file1 <-read.csv("/Users/Desktop/Master.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
file2 <-read.csv("/Users/Desktop/Detail.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
file3 <-read.csv("/Users/Desktop/file3.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)


CName <- levels(file1$Commodity_Name)

CName.lower <- tolower(CName)

correct_1 <- function(x){
  scores = stringdistmatrix(tolower(x), CName.lower, weight=c(1,0.001,1,0.5))
  if (min(scores)>2) {
    return("Others")
  } else {
    return(as.character(CName[which.min(scores)]))
  }
}


correct <- function(x) {
  sapply(as.character(x), correct_1)}


correctedfile2 <- file2 %>%
  transmute(Commodity.Name.Old = Commodity_Name, Commodity_Name = 

              correct(Commodity_Name))

file1$Commodity.Name = as.character(file1$Commodity_Name)


merged <- merge(file3,correctedfile2,all.correctedfile2=TRUE)
mm <- merged[,c("Commodity.Name.Old","Commodity_Name","Commodity_Category")]
```

Here, I'm providing 2 excel files. But now I want to make the second file dynamic. I want to design a html page which takes the commodity name as the input from the user and provides it to the R code for execution and gives the output as to which commodity category it belongs. I mean to say instead of Detail.csv I want to provide the form data to R.
Below is the HTML code

```
<body>
<p>Enter the commodity name </p>

<form id="myForm">
Commodity Name: <input type="text" name="Commodity Name" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>

<p>Click the "Submit" button to check the commodity category</p>

//R code runs and fetches the output
<p>The entered commodity belongs to Category --- </p>

</body>
</html>
```

After I submit, the commodity name should be passed to the R and give the output. I'm not getting how to link this HTML to R. 
I know I should use R Markdown and knitR package for this. After I click on SUBMIT I'm not getting how to pass this data to R.

Any kind of suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into https://www.opencpu.org/?

Comment: You can make a `shiny` app and let the user upload data. There are some [examples here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html) and a tutorial for you to start with [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'll go through the examples.

Comment: The other option is that if you can just make the R script a call from a PHP (or Python or …) CGI- or AJAX-based app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

server <- function(input, output) {

  file1 <- read.csv("/Users/Desktop/unspscList.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)

  CName <- levels(file1$Commodity_Name)
  CName.lower <- tolower(CName)

  correct_1 <- function(thing){
    scores = stringdistmatrix(tolower(thing), CName.lower, weight=c(1,0.001,1,0.5))
    if (min(scores)>2) {
      return("UNKNOWN")
    } else {
      return(as.character(CName[which.min(scores)]))
    }
  }

classify <- function(thing) {
    result <- file1 %>% filter( tolower(Commodity_Name) == tolower(sapply(as.character(thing), correct_1))  )
    print(paste0("The commodity Code is: ",result$Full_code))
    print(paste0("The commodity Category is: ",result$Level1_Description))
    print(paste0("The commodity Name is: ",result$Commodity_Name))
  }

  output$commodity <- renderText(

    if(input$commodity == "")
    {
      paste("You entered: ''")
    }
    else if(input$commodity == " ")
    {
      paste("You entered: 'Space'")
    }

    else
    {
      paste("You entered:", "'",input$commodity,"'")
    })

  ntext <- eventReactive(input$goButton, 
                         { if(input$commodity == "")
                         {
                           "Please enter a valid commodity name!"
                         }
                           else if(input$commodity == " ")
                           {
                             "Blank Space is not a valid commodity name! Try Again!"
                           }
                           else
                           {
                             classify(input$commodity)
                           }
                         }
  )


  output$classifiedThing <- renderPrint({
    ntext()
  })

}
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Commodity Classification App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("commodity", "Enter the Commodity Name:"),
      actionButton("goButton", "Classify!"),
      p("Click the classify button to View the commodity Category and code in the main panel.",
        style = "font-family: 'times'; font-si16pt ; color:purple "),

      tags$head(tags$style("#commodity{color: blue;
                           font-size: 15px;
                           font-style: italic;
                           }","body {background-color: PeachPuff;}"
                         )
      )



      ),
    mainPanel("Classification of Commodities",

              verbatimTextOutput("commodity"),
              verbatimTextOutput("classifiedThing"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small Shiny example:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # setup "do once" only things
  # if your data doesn't change much it should really be in 
  # an R data file
  file1 <- read.csv("Master.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE)

  # you have more code but this is a sample "classify" function
  classify <- function(thing) {
    file1 %>% filter(CommodityName == thing)
  }

  output$classifiedThing <- renderPrint({
    # this is where you'd call your classification function
    classify(input$commodity)
  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My Awesome Classification App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("commodity", "Commodity Name:", "Pen"),
      submitButton("Classify!")
    ),
    mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("classifiedThing"))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

That's a "single file Shiny app". If your code gets more complex, you may want to consider using separate `server.R` and `ui.R` files.

The [official Shiny tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/) is pretty good and you should be able to style & layout your app the way you need to. You may decide to use an `actionButton` vs a `submitButton` after reading the tutorial but that's up to you.

If the commodity list isn't huge, I'd suggest a pop-up menu to limit choices by the user vs free-form text.

Comment: Thanks hrbrmstr for the suggestion. Though it's looks a little complicated for me to understand i'll analyse and try it.

Comment: It works!!.. Thank you so much. Also I need to implement "stringdistmatrix" for matching the commodities. i.e, even if I enter 1 or 2 wrong letters in the commodity name I'm searching, I need to get the approximate match. But now only if I enter correct spelling I'm getting the output. Where can I implement this stringdistmatrix and calculate the minimum distance for match?

Comment: prbly in that `classify` function.

Comment: I also need to implement validation. If i enter nothing and click on classify, I need to throw an error message/ alert :Please enter the commodity name! Is it possible with Submit Button? I tried with action button, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/download-knitr-reports.html) example in the shiny gallery. It is for downloading a knitr report.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this would be more helpful if they included the code for the original 'report.Rmd' document